# How to set cutoff while training the data in Random Forest in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, random-forest, apache-spark-mllib

I am using Spark Mlib to train the data for classification using Random Forest Algorithm. The MLib provides a **RandomForest** Class which has *trainClassifier* Method which does the required.

Can I set a threshold value while training the data set, similar to the ***cutoff*** option provided in R's *randomForest* Package.

http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/randomForest/randomForest.pdf

I found the **RandomForest** Class of MLib provides options only to pass number of trees, impurity, number of classes etc but there is nothing like **threshold** or **cut off** option available. Can it be done by any way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short version is no, if we look at `RandomForestClassifier.scala` you can see that it always simply selects the max. You could override the predict function if, but its not super clean. I've added a jira to track adding this.