# How to upgrade Apache Spark version

Tags: apache-spark, spark-ec2

Currently, I have installed Spark 1.5.0 version on AWS using spark-ec2.sh script.

Now, I want to upgrade my Spark version to 1.5.1. How do i do this? Is there any upgrade procedure or do i have to build it from scratch using the spark-ec2 script? In that case i will lose all my existing configuration.

Please Advise

Thanks

Comment: Check my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32259015/predict-class-probabilities-in-spark-randomforestclassifier/32278192#32278192) on  the part concerning AWS.

Comment: @eliasah i am not using any EMR and S3 on AWS

Answer (score 0):

`1.5.1` has identical configuration fields with the `1.5.0`, I am not aware of any automation tools, but upgrade should be trivial. C/P `$SPARK_HOME/conf` should suffice. Back up the old files, nevertheless.

Comment: yes fine but spark-ec2.sh script done some extra configuration for Spark on AWS. So how i built spark from source without knowing all settings and configuration.