# How to install a custom spark branch on EMR?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-csv

I want my AWS EMR to have a particular branch of Spark from the git repo instead of default Spark.

The reason I want to do this is, I want to use a branch which has a fix for null value for csv.

Comment: Are you asking about Spark or the spark-csv project?

Comment: the bug is in the latest stable version of spark (2.0.0)

Comment: And which bug is that? Can you link to the issue in the Spark issue tracker?

Comment: its already there in the spark issue tracker and the solution is already provided by a dev  https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-16460

Comment: How did you currently get Spark installed? What is preventing you from checking out the pull request and compiling Spark yourself

Comment: @cricket_007 On EMR, you can install spark by configuration but each emr image has 1 version of spark. ex: emr-5.0.0 -> spark 2.0.0 the issue is that EMR has ephemeral file systems which means that each time you terminate, you'll loose all the disks content.

Comment: It might not sure if this still works, but I have presented here a way to install custom spark on emr http://stackoverflow.com/a/32278192/3415409